# How to debug a bluetooth keyboard connection. Some keys not recognized on raspberry pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have 2 raspberry pi's
rpi2b+ with buster
rpi3b with buster

I have a remote shutter (this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33041323857.html) that i pair with the rpi's over Bluetooth, and it is recognized as a remote keyboard.
the big (iOS) key sends keycode 115
the small(android) key sends keycode 28

when paired with the rpi3b, showkey detects both keys

```
pi@RPi-Rob-usb:~ $ sudo showkey
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode 115 press
keycode 115 release

keycode  28 press
keycode  28 release
```

when paired with the rpi2b+, showkey does not detect keycode 115

```
pi@RPi-Rob:~ $ sudo showkey
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 press
keycode  28 release
```

```
pi@RPi-Rob:~ $ uname -a
Linux RPi-Rob 5.4.51-v7+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:45:19 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@RPi-Rob:~ $ 


pi@RPi-Rob-usb:~ $ uname -a
Linux RPi-Rob-usb 5.4.51-v7+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:45:19 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@RPi-Rob-usb:~ $
```

how can I make the rpi2b+ recognize the keycode 115?
is there a lower level tool that shows what is actually received on the pi side.

Comment: Can you do a `uname -a` on both machines and update your question with the result. Thanks.

Comment: done. as you can see the os's are the same.

Comment: You might want to have a read through https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116731/121848 and  https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/issues/8 to see if it applies to your situation. You can find out what version you currently have installed with `dpkg -l | grep "bluez-firmware\|pi-bluetooth"`

Comment: @ukBaz. That did not apply to my situation. i did get a little further, after a reboot the keycode 115 came back, only to disappear mysteriously an hour later. Still investigating. the article did give me some pointers to pursue. thanks for that.